# IE prevent select list change event on keyboard scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with the change event on a select list in IE vs Chrome. When the option list is closed the change event in IE fires when scrolling through the list with the keyboard. In Chrome with change event does not fire when scrolling.

What is the best way to have IE behave like Chrome?

http://jsfiddle.net/mTLrY/4/

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>

$('select').change(function(){
    alert('changing');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using onBlur instead of onchange. onblur is for when the control looses focus, which sounds like what you might actually want. I'm pretty sure the jquery is just `$('select').blur(function(){...`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the `onchange` attribute in the select tag. Fire the required javascript function when the state of this select list has changed.

Comment: Appears to have to same behavior as the original